# Management metadata quotas SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, quota, mms

We are a part of a main organisation and we have a selection of site collections but no access to the tenancy itself.  We have managed metadata which is global which we all can use and then we have Site Collection managed metadata sets which we can create on our site collections. We have now gone over the quota.. Is the quota for both global and site collection combined or is it two different quotas.. The documentation for the quotas is very poor indeed.

Answer (score 0):

[as per the documentation 200,000 terms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits) in term store is for tenant. Please [check this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_shareon/about-sharepoint-online-term-store/cee617c3-8431-465c-a78c-da7d82e04ce3) for where MSFT guy responded.

I would recommend you to open a support ticket to get the clear answer from MSFT.

Comment: Yes thats fair enough and thank you - but is that overall between the global term store and the local site collection term store.. Or are they different quotas.

Comment: as per my understanding it is combined.